# Почему sizeof битового поля в 64 бита равен 12, а не 8?

Tags: c++, g++

Неожиданный для меня поворот:

```
struct frame_head
{
    unsigned size   : 24;
    unsigned height : 12;
    unsigned width  : 12;
    unsigned pts    : 15;
    bool key        :  1;
};
printf("%d\n", sizeof(frame_head)); // 12... Но почему не 8???
```

Зачем GNU g++ надо ещё 4 байта, если там всего заказано 64 бита / 8 байт?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field The following properties of bit fields are implementation-defined: [..] Whether a bit field can straddle an allocation unit boundary 

Вангую, что allocation unit это 4 байта и они поделились (size) (height, width) (pts, key) = 12 байт

Comment: При чем интересно если сделать unsigned size   : 20; то результат будет 8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что упаковка работает так:

```
struct frame_head
{
    unsigned size   : 24;   // под это поле зарезервируется слово (32-бита) потому что следующее поле не влезает в слово
    ////////////////////
    unsigned height : 12;
    unsigned width  : 12;   // под эти 2 поля зарезервируется слово (32-бита) потому что следующее поле не влезает в слово
    ////////////////////
    unsigned pts    : 15;
    bool key        :  1;   // под эти 2 поля зарезервируется слово (32-бита)
};
```

ответ к первому комментарию:

```
struct frame_head
{
    unsigned size   : 20;
    unsigned height : 12;   // под эти 2 поля зарезервируется слово (32-бита) потому что следующее поле не влезает в слово
    ////////////////////
    unsigned width  : 12;   
    unsigned pts    : 15;
    bool key        :  1;   // под эти 3 поля зарезервируется слово (32-бита)
};
```

Comment: да проверь свои догадки тогда при unsigned size : 20 и на unsigned size : 21 в этой структуре. Действительно неожиданно 8 и 12

Comment: @ Aziz Umarov поправил ответ

Comment: Да заметил, компилятор заполняет до слово и чтоб порядок не менялся

Comment: А компиляторы не умеют их автоматически оптимально упаковывать. Ведь если какими-то низкоуровневыми хаками не пользоваться, то на кой чёрт программисту об этом париться?

Comment: @Egorithm еще и порядок их не опрелен, на некоторых системах он может быть обратным. Можно пытаться установить упаковку структуры в  (1) но не факт что не будет выравнивания по началу байта (Микрокософт поддерживает). Надежне сделать шаблон для геттеров\сеттеров

Answer (score 1):

Скажите компилятору что все поля упаковываются в 64-битную ячейку памяти - memory location, и если вся последовательность полей с ненулевой длиной  помещается в таковое, они ее займут.
Поле height не помещается в unsigned -32 битное слово и занимает новое слово. Лучше использовать типы с гарантированным размером - uint64_t   и пр.